# how to i can to find webhook address in my telegram bot?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I create a bot in telegram and set webhook in my domain address.
Now i want to change my domain bot i forget page of webhook in my website.
Is there a way I can find my robot's webhook address?

my website create by asp.net mvc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo

You could try the `getWebhookInfo` method. It returns the URL along with other information.

[Ref doc here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo).

Answer (score 0):

**To be able to find your webhook address, you must use the following link**

```
https://api.telegram.org/botYourToken/getWebhookInfo
```

just replace token Instead "YourToken"